# Should Romberg's method always be more accurate than specified?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm using the Romberg's method found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg%27s_method#Implementation. It's usually very good, but for
[image]
I often get an error much bigger than the desired accuracy.
For example, when I integrate from 1 to 3, a= 0.749618467298147 and the **desired accuracy is 10<sup>-7</sup>**, the algorithm stops (without reaching the maximum number of iterations) with:

```
Romberg       : 2.92489712953285
Correct result: 2.92474011214362
```

the error is 1.57 · 10<sup>-4</sup>, while the estimated accuracy returned by the Romberg algorithm is 2.25 · 10<sup>-8</sup> (Simpson's composite method performs much better: the error is 4.336 · 10<sup>-9</sup>).

Should I expect this unwanted behavior often or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Using my Romberg routine using your numbers, I get $$2.924740112143528$$ Could there be an issue with your implementation?

Comment: I can even increase accuracy and get $$2.924740112143616$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful example of the "failure" of Rombergs method. First of all, I can replicate your experience using the C code from the wiki. Secondly, the convergence criterion used by the implementation makes very little sense to me. Better error estimates are available. Third, even with a better error estimate, Romberg method aborts before we are inside the asymptotic range where  the error estimates are valid. Try lowering the tolerance to 1e-8 or smaller and I think you will be happy. Additional analysis (and time) is needed before I can attempt an answer.

Comment: @CarlChristian I agree that the convergence criterion doesn't work, but the algorithm works, in the sense that the correct result to 15-digit accuracy is obtained at the 7th row, 3rd column. Probably the algorithm should be stopped only when 2 consecutive results are identical.

Comment: Since neither Simpson nor Romberg has a reliable stopping condition, the best option for me is probably to use the Gauss-Legendre code found here: http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/numerical-methods/numerical-integration/ iterating from n= 16 ... 1024 until two consecutive results have a "small" difference; n= 16 seems fine in most cases.